# Blender Topology and UV editing, how to put a tileable texture on a curved mesh? How to make the topology better?

Tags: textures, blender, texture-mapping, topology

I made a ship, but now im trying to put a tileable wood texture on it.
It works well, except at a few points in the mesh.

I gave the model some *Seams*, then I *Unwrap*.
Then I take one UVFace tile and make it square by scaling its edges.
Finally I select that squared face, then click L to select all Linked Faces.
Then I open context menu and choose Follow Active Quads.

This results in all curved UV faces, now becoming squared and straight.

However some faces stay curved and this is messing up the UVs and the final result as we can see with the texture applied:
[image: straight UV Faces result]
[image: origina topology for above result]

So this wasnt working, so I tried cleaning up the topology, by making everything into 4 sided quads best as I could, but I ended up with 2 triangles as it was not possible in any other way to make this topology.

Heres the result after doing the same thing as before > Unwrap > Make Square > Follow Active Quads:

[image: new topology]
[image: new topology textured]

So as you can see, this didnt fix it, in some areas it looks better, but in others it just made it much worse...

What is the correct way to get a tileable texture to be rendered straight/ how do I manipulate the UVs or the toplogy to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: How do I topolology?